# Beamer Sectionpage for \section*{} command

Tags: beamer, starred-version

In Beamer one can get a section slide every time the \section{} command is called. However, I would like that not to happen when I use the \section*{} command.

So in the example below, I would like there to be no section page for the Overview section. (In my real template the section title shows up in the bottom left corner, so I do need the \section command.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Ilmenau}

\defbeamertemplate*{section page}{ifttheme}%[1][]
{\vbox{}\vskip-3.2cm%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,ht=0.5\paperheight,wd=\paperwidth]{red}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{minipage}[c]{0.55\paperwidth}
        \centering\insertsection%\par
        \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
\end{beamercolorbox}
}

\AtBeginSection{\frame{\sectionpage}}

\begin{document}

\section*{Overview}

\begin{frame}{Lorem}
\begin{itemize}
\item Ipsum
\item Dolor
\item Sit
\item \dots
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{Lorem Ipsum}

\subsection{Dolor sit amet}

\begin{frame}{Using a bilinear approximation}
bla
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an empty optional argument for the optional argument of `\AtBeginSection`, as in

```
\AtBeginSection[]%<- do nothing for starred sections
  {\frame{\sectionpage}}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Ilmenau}

\defbeamertemplate*{section page}{ifttheme}%[1][]
{\vbox{}\vskip-3.2cm%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,ht=0.5\paperheight,wd=\paperwidth]{red}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{minipage}[c]{0.55\paperwidth}
        \centering\insertsection%\par
        \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
\end{beamercolorbox}
}

\AtBeginSection[]{\frame{\sectionpage}}

\begin{document}

\section*{Overview}

\begin{frame}{Lorem}
\begin{itemize}
\item Ipsum
\item Dolor
\item Sit
\item \dots
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{Lorem Ipsum}

\subsection{Dolor sit amet}

\begin{frame}{Using a bilinear approximation}
bla
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]